# what is the nagios performance data format

Tags: performance, format, output, nagios

I am looking for a spec or an example of how to format the Nagios performance data.

This [documentation](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/perfdata.html) does not provide any good examples
I am looking for an explanation on how to create a table like this in Thruk / Nagios output.

[image: Perfomance Data output]

Raw Data :
`pending=3;5500;7000 complete=18940;; error=454;;7000`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found [this page](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#AEN200) which describes in some detail how to format the performance data.

This is the expected format:

`'label'=value[UOM];[warn];[crit];[min];[max]`

Notes:

1. space separated list of label/value pairs
2. label can contain any characters except the equals sign or single quote (')
3. the single quotes for the label are optional. Required if spaces are in the label
4. label length is arbitrary, but ideally the first 19 characters are unique (due to a limitation in RRD). Be aware of a limitation in the amount of data that NRPE returns to Nagios
5. to specify a quote character, use two single quotes
6. warn, crit, min or max may be null (for example, if the threshold is not defined or min and max do not apply). Trailing unfilled semicolons can be dropped
7. min and max are not required if UOM=%
8. value, min and max in class [-0-9.]. Must all be the same UOM. value may be a literal "U" instead, this would indicate that the actual value couldn't be determined
9. warn and crit are in the range format (see the Section called Threshold and ranges). Must be the same UOM

   10. UOM (unit of measurement) is one of:

       - no unit specified - assume a number (int or float) of things (eg, users, processes, load averages)
       - s - seconds (also us, ms)
       - % - percentage
       - B - bytes (also KB, MB, TB)
       - c - a continous counter (such as bytes transmitted on an interface)

It is up to third party programs to convert the Nagios Plugins performance data into graphs.

In my this case the raw data provides a pefect example of the output required.

`pending=3;5500;7000 complete=18940;; error=454;;7000`